# Why Angular 2+ structural directive doesn't update the view?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

In my application I have an account service which has permissions array, So I created a structural directive to decide whether showing an action's button or not, but the problem is that when I do login/logout and update the permissions array, the directive doesn't update the view.

here is the code:

```ts
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Account } from './models';
import { AccountService } from './account.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAuth]',
})
export class AuthDirective {

  @Input() set appAuth(action: string) {
    if (this._account.permissions.includes(action)) {
      this._contRef.createEmbeddedView(this._tmplRef);
    } else {
      this._contRef.clear();
    }
  }

  constructor(
    private _contRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private _tmplRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private _account: AccountService
  ) { }

}
```

Here is an example of the usage of the directive:

```html
<button
  class="btn btn-default"
  *appAuth="'find-accounts'"
  (click)="doSomething()">
  Find Accounts
</button>
```

Comment: I'm not so sure that it has to update the view with this code, because before the login and after the login the directive's `@Input()` parameter is still the same (`'find-accounts'`), so nothing's changed.

Comment: I have the opinion, but how to work around it?

Comment: Your directive has to know somehow when a logout or a login event has happened. Maybe try to move your condition into ngOnInit, and implement a service, that can notify your directive, when something happened. With the help of a Subject, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```ts
import { Account, AccountService } from '../common';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import {
  Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, OnInit, OnDestroy
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAuth]',
})
export class AuthDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private _accountChangesSubscription: Subscription;

  @Input('appAuth') private appAuth: string;

  constructor(
    private _contRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private _tmplRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private _account: AccountService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._accountChangesSubscription = this._account.changes$
      .subscribe((account: Account) => {
        const permissions = this._account.permissions;

        if (permissions && permissions.includes(this.appAuth)) {
          this._contRef.createEmbeddedView(this._tmplRef);
        } else {
          this._contRef.clear();
        }
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._accountChangesSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```